# Crime data @ Zip code level?

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, demographics, postal-code, crime

I mainly need property-type crimes but all crimes will work. I'm mainly looking for downloadable crime data that is at the ZIP5 level if possible. The more granular the better. The next best would be county I think.

However, I am looking for a dataset that applies to the entire US. There seem to be crime stats for specific cities but that won't really work for my use case.

Comment: zip codes don't map out 1:1 with localities, aside from the fact that criminal justice data in america is a anything but standardized. maybe you can find fbi data to try and match up to zip codes, but thats not what you want, and more work. sorry to be negative here, but i don't think this data exists on the national level.

Comment: @albert no worries! I've basically already concluded this doesn't exist so I figured last resort is to post here to see if anyone knows something I don't lol

Comment: i have a zip code crime data for york county, virginia for a couple of years. not sure if that helps.

Comment: I don't think that will really help with my use case. I kinda need the entire US for this task. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: The closest answer is probably the one posted for this question: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/are-there-any-gis-crime-datasets-open-to-public. If you can find crime data which is geolocated in any way (eg, with lat/long coordinates), it's a simple GIS task to assign zip codes.

Comment: related: [How ZIP codes nearly masked the lead problem in Flint](https://theconversation.com/how-zip-codes-nearly-masked-the-lead-problem-in-flint-65626)